# react-native Linking.addEventListener callback using this.setState error

Tags: react-native

[image]

```
 componentDidMount() {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', event => this._handleOpenURL(event.url));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        Linking.removeEventListener('url', event => this._handleOpenURL(event.url));
    }

    _handleOpenURL(url) {
        this.setState({url: url});
    }
```

how to solve this problem？